# Why doesn't make unexport directive work?

Tags: makefile

I would expect the `unexport` make directive to unset a variable. From reading online it seems like that's what it's supposed to do:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html

> If you want to prevent a variable from being exported, use the unexport directive, like this:
>
> unexport variable …

So I made a small example. In my first run `BAR` isn't set and as expected nothing is printed; however, then I set an environment variable. I would expect nothing to be printed because I'm using the `unexport` directive, except the value `dogs` still gets printed.

```
$ cat Makefile
unexport BAR

foo:
    @echo BAR=$(BAR)
$ make
BAR=
$ export BAR=dogs
$ make
BAR=dogs
$ uname -a
Darwin Maxs-MacBook-Pro-Work.local 19.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
$ man make | grep unexport
```

What's going on here? Why is dogs still printed?

Comment: `unexport`ing a variable doesn't delete the it, it just... well... *unexport*s it. It's not in a child process's environment (when `make` does in fact start a child proces); that doesn't mean it doesn't exist at all. Have your target run `env`, if you want the effect to be visible, or something like `bash -c 'declare -p BAR'`.

Comment: Using `env | grep '^BAR='; true`, `BAR` is not exported to the sub-process (`env`).  The `true` is needed because `grep` fails when it doesn't find `BAR` in the output of `env`.  Tested on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.  With the `unexport` line commented out and values set for `BAR` (explicitly on the command line, or in the environment), the output includes `BAR=<set value>`.

Comment: First you unexport the variable and it's not in the output, then you explicitly export it and it is in the output. What else did you expect?

Comment: I was expecting the unexport directive inside the Makefile to unexport the variable that I exported in the shell. What's the purpose of the unexport directive if it doesn't unexport a variable?

Comment: To the point of unexporting it from the env of the executed processes. You example using Make (not environmental) variable, it literally passes `echo BAR=dogs` to shell executing the recipe. If you however change it to say: `@echo BAR=$${BAR}`, would tell that shell to: `@echo BAR=${BAR}` which would then get you `BAR=` with the variable not being exported.